# I need to put in lower level an object

Tags: html, css

i have made a scrolling manu and when I try to select it the list of the menu goes behind of an object (a simple music player). How can i put that object in lower level? I know I should use z-index command but i don't know the value. I tried them all.

```
z-index:0; 
z-index:1; 
z-index:auto;
```

Whatelse can I use?

Comment: I doubt you really tried all z-index values.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle/code sample?

Comment: Instead of setting the object on a lower z-index level you should set your list on a higher z-index level such as z-index:100 for example. For z-index to function the element must also have a position defined as either relative, absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting that `z-index` is only obeyed on `position`ed elements (`absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`). If you put a `z-index` on a non-positioned (`static`) element, it will be ignored.

The value of `z-index` is any integer or `auto`;

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works on explicitly positioned elements with a `position` of `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

additionally, their 'stacking context' is relative to their position in the DOM.  two sibling elements are in the same stacking context, but their children elements are in a new stacking context (so if you have two sibling parents with `z-index: 1`, and one of them has an immediate child with `z-index: 1` and the other has an immediate child with `z-index: 2`, the latter will have the higher `z-index` because its stacking context is 1-2 versus 1-1.  However if for example you have two parent sibling elements where one has a higher z-index than the other, no descendant of the parent with the lower `z-index` will ever have a higher z-index than children of the parent with the higher `z-index`, even if you set the former's children to `z-index: 500` or something like that.  Basically stacking contexts exist at each level of the DOM and their effects cascade to all of the lower stacking contexts generated by their descendants.

`z-index` is tricky to master and requires a lot of attention to the markup and DOM structure.  you need to post all of the relevant CSS and HTML in order for us to help you.

You can read some more about z-index on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index)